# BE users don't have access to localization

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

This Localization column, other Backend users don't have it. How to make it possible?

[image]

Comment: Logged in user needs to be have access to all languages. by your list module and root you can have setting of usergroup access.

Comment: Under "Edit Usergroup" I enabled all languages: http://i.imgur.com/rUp8xbl.png - but still no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the list module, a user has to scroll down until she reaches three checkboxes. Checking "Localization view" enables the columns you are refering to.

[image: Enable the Localization View]